# Can we write 10 million rows in File(.dat) using step "Text File Output" in Pentaho Data Integration? and it is readable in pentaho data integration?

Tags: pentaho

I want to write 10 million rows in .dat file using setp "Text file output" in PDI. this is possible and if possible then it is readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write data to Text file for even more than (10 Million) records.

Comment: What do you mean by readable and how? How do you want to read it?

Comment: Thanks sir, I want to write 10 million rows in ".dat" file using step "file output". After writing the ".dat" file the size of file is greater than 2 GB. Read rows in that file using step "Table Input" (using "Bulk Select Query" in Table Input) in Pentah Data Integration. this is possible in PDI?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can use Text file output - Just use "dat" as Extension
2. Read the file with "Text file input" - Just add the .dat file and use the Seperator used in the output step